# Is android's accelerometer data normalized to the center of the device?

Tags: android, api, accelerometer, android-sensors

When using the [accelerometer (calibrated)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) api is the accelerometer data the acceleration from the position of the physical accelerometer on the devices motherboard or the center of the phone?

[image]

If the sensor is located far away from the centre of the device the measurement will be amplified as rotation at the edges of the device will be faster than at the centre. Naturally when using the sensor for precise measurements it would be better to have data from the middle of the device in order to get more consistent results across different device sizes.

Comment: I don't think so, as a sensor, it just gives data to Android, and I don't think it takes care to fix that data in order to make it according to device centre, because, as you said, the sensor is located in different locations, depending on the manufacturer

Comment: Yeah, but surely the calibration should do this by using the gyroscope data and multiple accelerometer data points to figure out the position... no?

Comment: Well, is an interesting idea, but i still thinking that is so much work for manufacturers to do so, just imagine, they would have to program a different calibration for each model device, since a slightly different sensor location would change everything. Probably most premium models could actually have this (like galaxies SX,  Motorola ZX, etc. ), but for budget devices I don't think so

Comment: I would thank that Android does this under the hood when first setting up or over time as it is used the first few hours or days. If not a one time thing that a manufacturer has to do, In theory all they need to do is wiggle a final prototype model around a bit and copy paste the calibration values into the final android OS build that gets put into production.